# Vue: Firebase: Error in mounted hook: "FirebaseError: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, firebase-authentication

I am building Vue SPA and have checked many posts before posting this.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Below is my App.Vue:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <Navigation />
        <router-view class="container" :user="user" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Navigation from '@/components/Navigation.vue';
// import db from './db.js';
import Firebase from 'firebase';
export default {
    name: 'App',
    data: function() {
        return {
            user: null,
        };
    },
    mounted() {

        Firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if (user) {
                this.user = user.email;
            }
        });
    },
    components: {
        Navigation,
    },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
$primary: #37c6cf;
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
</style>
```

**Note:** I have commmented the import from db.js  which can be find after the first import. If I enable it Vue CLI is throwing different error.

in db.js:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: 'yourkey',
    authDomain: 'domainnew.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'yourdomain.com',
    projectId: 'yourproject',
    storageBucket: 'test',
    messagingSenderId: '454545',
    appId: '1:444d96:web:d78df',
    measurementId: 'G-69599595',
};

// Initialize firebase
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();
export default firebaseApp.firestore();
```

In the console I am keep getting below two errors and my Vue is not retrieving my email address from Firebase.

[image]

Can any one pleas help on this.

Comment: Where is your firebase configuration? Where are you initializing the firebase application? Did you happen to read the instructions  https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase#npm-bundler-browserify-webpack-etc . You need to import firebase and initialize with your configuration provided by firebase console for this app.

Comment: sorry it is on the db.js. I am initializing my firebase on this file.

Comment: You would export/import an instance of firebase app, not firebase itself.

Comment: Have updated my db.js code. because I am not mounting anything from db.js. If I enable the import statement of db.js. Vue cli is throwing error

Comment: Since you don't import `db.js` into the `App.Vue`, it seems to me that the `FirebaseApp` won't be initialized, which in turn would explain the error. If you're having a hard time making the import work, you might want to first get things working without an import, so by having the `firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)` directly inside `App.Vue` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

### db.js file

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import "firebase/analytics";
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: 'yourkey',
    authDomain: 'domainnew.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'yourdomain.com',
    projectId: 'yourproject',
    storageBucket: 'test',
    messagingSenderId: '454545',
    appId: '1:444d96:web:d78df',
    measurementId: 'G-69599595',
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);



const db = firebase.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const analytics = firebase.analytics();

export { db, auth, analytics };
```

### App.js file

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <Navigation />
        <router-view class="container" :user="user" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Navigation from '@/components/Navigation.vue';
const fb = require('./db.js');

export default {
    name: 'App',
    data: function() {
        return {
            user: null,
        };
    },
    mounted() {

        fb.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if (user) {
                this.user = user.email;
            }
        });
    },
    components: {
        Navigation,
    },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
$primary: #37c6cf;
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
</style>
```

Comment: @RagavanRajan Hi, did you have time to look at the proposed solution? Thx

Comment: Sorry for the delay in this. Work like a charm :) Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi @RagavanRajan, happy that I could help you! You may also upvote the answer if you think it was helpful! Thanks :-)

Comment: Sure. Thanks again